# Kafka Streams Multiple binder configuration not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to use two Kafka Streams binder in the same application, but something I do wrong because I am not able to use config of second binder with different applicationId.

application.yml

First binder config:

```
spring.cloud.stream.binders.kafka1.type: kstream
spring.cloud.stream.binders.kafka1.environment.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.messagetoProcess-in-0.consumer.application-id: ID1
spring.cloud.stream.binders.kafka1.environment.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.application-id: ID2
spring.cloud.stream.binders.kafka1.environment.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.autoAddPartitions: true
spring.cloud.stream.binders.kafka1.environment.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.minPartitionCount: 3
spring.cloud.stream.binders.kafka1.environment.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.replicationFactor: 2
spring.cloud.stream.binders.kafka1.environment.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.serdeError: logAndContinue
spring.cloud.stream.binders.kafka1.environment.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.brokers: hub.corp:9092,hub.corp:9092,hub.corp:9092
spring.cloud.stream.binders.kafka1.environment.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.acks: all
spring.cloud.stream.binders.kafka1.environment.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.compression.type: gzip
spring.cloud.stream.binders.kafka1.environment.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.max.request.size: 104857600
spring.cloud.stream.binders.kafka1.environment.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.cache.max.bytes.buffering: 104857600
spring.cloud.stream.binders.kafka1.environment.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.commit.interval.ms: 20000
spring.cloud.stream.binders.kafka1.environment.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.windowstore.changelog.additional.retention.ms: 86400000
spring.cloud.stream.binders.kafka1.environment.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.processing.guarantee: exactly_once
spring.cloud.stream.binders.kafka1.environment.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.replication.factor: 2
spring.cloud.stream.binders.kafka1.environment.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.default.key.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
spring.cloud.stream.binders.kafka1.environment.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.default.value.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde


spring.cloud.stream.bindings.messagetoProcess-in-0.destination: test_messagetoProcess
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.messagetoProcess-in-0.group: test_consumer_messagetoProcess
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.messagetoProcess-in-0.binder: kafka1

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.messagetoProcess-out-0.destination: test_processedMessages
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.messagetoProcess-out-0.binder: kafka1
```

Second binder config:

```
spring.cloud.stream.binders.kafka2.type: kstream
spring.cloud.stream.binders.kafka2.environment.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.richMessagetoProcess-in-0.consumer.application-id: ID3
spring.cloud.stream.binders.kafka2.environment.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.application-id: ID4
spring.cloud.stream.binders.kafka2.environment.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.autoAddPartitions: true
spring.cloud.stream.binders.kafka2.environment.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.minPartitionCount: 3
spring.cloud.stream.binders.kafka2.environment.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.replicationFactor: 2
spring.cloud.stream.binders.kafka2.environment.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.serdeError: logAndContinue
spring.cloud.stream.binders.kafka2.environment.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.brokers: hub.corp:9092,hub.corp:9092,hub.corp:9092
spring.cloud.stream.binders.kafka2.environment.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.acks: all
spring.cloud.stream.binders.kafka2.environment.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.compression.type: gzip
spring.cloud.stream.binders.kafka2.environment.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.max.request.size: 104857600
spring.cloud.stream.binders.kafka2.environment.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.cache.max.bytes.buffering: 104857600
spring.cloud.stream.binders.kafka2.environment.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.commit.interval.ms: 1000
spring.cloud.stream.binders.kafka2.environment.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.windowstore.changelog.additional.retention.ms: 86400000
spring.cloud.stream.binders.kafka2.environment.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.processing.guarantee: exactly_once
spring.cloud.stream.binders.kafka2.environment.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.replication.factor: 2
spring.cloud.stream.binders.kafka2.environment.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.default.key.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
spring.cloud.stream.binders.kafka2.environment.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.default.value.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde


spring.cloud.stream.bindings.richMessagetoProcess-in-0.destination: test_richMessagetoProcess
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.richMessagetoProcess-in-0.group: test_consumer_richMessagetoProcess
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.richMessagetoProcess-in-0.binder: kafka2

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.richMessagetoProcess-out-0.destination: test_richProcessedMessages
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.richMessagetoProcess-out-0.binder: kafka2
```

additionally I have two stateStores

```
aggregation.messagetoProcess.stateStoreName: test_messagetoProcess
aggregation.richMessagetoProcess.stateStoreName: test_RichmessagetoProcess
```

When my app is started in Kafka Broker I see next changelog & repartition names:

```
ID1-test_messagetoProcess-changelog
ID1-test_messagetoProcess-repartition

ID2-test_RichmessagetoProcess-changelog
ID2-test_RichmessagetoProcess-repartition
```

kafka2 binder is not used and *applicationId* ID3, ID4 not exists in logs. For both streams, configuration of binder 1 has been applied...but I need different configuration for each binder.

**Question:**

I have something wrong? How I can get the desired behavior?

**Additionally** when my stream do aggregation with multiple instance (3 POD's in Openshift) only one of them do aggregation, theoretically with this configuration the 3 POD's must work simultaneously.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your code?  Just looking at logs is not enough.

Comment: In addition to the code and topology, what is your use case? Why would you prefer to have both KafkaStreams applications within the same application? Even if so, why are you defining different applicationId (~ different KafkaStreams applications) within the same application? This needs more clarity. It seems like you're trying an overcomplicated solution.